# sencha architect theme/css change based on profile/ device type

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have rectally started using sencha architect for sencha touch devlopment.

Earlier I would use the profiling of the application to differentiate in the css being loaded for the application based on the device. As for devices like mac mini the tool bar height is less that can be increased from default as compared to other device.

In Sencha Architect theme is being used which has its scss file being loaded, but did not find a option to change theme.

Please correct me if I wrong or missed any step I need to do to achieve the required output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create 2 themes on architect --> resources
2. on app.json add
   `"builds": {
     "NameProfile1": {
        "theme": "theme-crisp-d8aec586-e27f-458a-a90a-541fc781ad15"
     },
     "NameProfile2": {
        "theme": "theme-crisp-touch-e3a4f7f7-77c6-44af-966b-c09d1fab2b0c"
    } 
   },`
3. Build

now use

http://localhost:8080/?profile=NameProfile1

or

http://localhost:8080/?profile=NameProfile2